# VueJS router.push() issue

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm going straight to the point here. I'm doing an authentication on the login page, after clicking the login page it redirects me to a product's component and on that product's component, I do an `HTTP request` to get all the products. However, after logging in and redirecting on the products page the product's component seems it can't run my `HTTP request` on the `created()` lifecycle hooks. Is this a normal behaviour?

Here's my code:

**LOGIN:**

```js
export default{
        data(){
            return {
                email: '',
                password: ''
            }
        },
        methods:{
            login(){
                var data = {
                    client_id: 2,
                    client_secret: 'TOKEN_HERE,
                    grant_type: 'password',
                    username: this.email,
                    password: this.password
                }

                this.$http.post("oauth/token", data).then(response => {
                    this.$auth.setToken(response.body.access_token, response.body.expires_in + Date.now())
                    this.$router.push('/products')
                })

            }
        }
```

**PRODUCTS.VUE**

```js
   import Products from './product/Products.vue'
    export default {
        components: {
            'my-products' : Products
        },
        created(){
          this.$http.get('api/products')
            .then(response => {
                alert("products from feed");
                this.products = response.body
            })
        }
    }
```

after redirecting to `products.vue` created lifecycle hook, it can't run my http request.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean *can't run*? What is happening? The `created` hook is not triggering?

Comment: @acdcjunior when I login successfully, I will be redirected to `products component` using this.$router.push('/products').. after the redirection the `created()` lifecyclye hook can't run my `http request`.. it gives me error on my console `uncaught (in promise)`

Comment: Then catch it and see: `this.$http.get('api/products')
            .then(response => {
                alert("products from feed");
                this.products = response.body
            }, err => console.log('error is:', err));` can you paste the error here?

Comment: @acdcjunior will do.. give me a second.

Comment: @acdcjunior Hi sir error message says I am `Unauthenticated`.. however I am 100% sure I am authenticated... when I refresh the page it shows me all the products... however, the initial load of the page after `this.$router.push` gives me unauthorized error

Comment: pls check the http request in [Chrome devtool network panel](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/resource-loading#network_panel_overview) and check if your auth token is passed correctly.

Comment: hi @JacobGoh it seems that the token hasn't been registered after the the redirection.. however, when I refresh the browser my `http request` is working fine.

Comment: "`http request` working fine" meaning that the token is registered correctly after refresh ?

Comment: @JacobGoh correct.. it's registered after refresh.

Comment: then my guess is that `this.$auth.setToken` is asynchronous, and when `this.$router.push('/products')` is executed, `setToken` hasn't finished running.

Comment: is it okay to do this before redirecting?
`Vue.http.headers.common['Authorization'] = Vue.auth.getToken();`

Comment: but the problem is that the token is not yet set before redirecting. so `Vue.auth.getToken();` would be empty at the time, isn't it ? you are using `vue-authenticate` right ? have you tried https://github.com/dgrubelic/vue-authenticate#custom-request-and-response-interceptors?

Comment: no, sir..., but almost the same...

Comment: I can't find a pretty way to solve this. Either you gotta edit the auth library you are using to add a callback function to `setToken`, or you will need to write a function to recursively check if `Vue.auth.getToken()` is not empty, and only redirect after you make sure that it's not empty.

Comment: hi @JacobGoh.. noted on this.. thanks..

Answer (score 1):

I seems like you need `mounted` hook instead.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks